# When do the rights granted by a design patent vest in the USA?

Tags: patent-lifetime, design-patent

Do they vest once the design patent is granted or do they go back to some period earlier (retroactive)? I’m asking specifically about design patents.

Answer (score 1):

The term of a design patent is 14 years measured from the date of grant.

> [1502.01   Distinction Between Design and Utility Patents [R-11.2013]](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1502.html)
>
> The term of a utility patent on an application filed
> on or after June 8, 1995 is 20 years measured from the U.S. filing
> date; or if the application contains a specific reference to an
> earlier application under 35 U.S.C. 120, 121, or 365(c), 20 years from
> the earliest effective U.S. filing date, while *the term of a design
> patent is 14 years measured from the date of grant* (see 35 U.S.C. 173).
>
> [1505 Allowance and Term of Design Patent [R-08.2012]](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1505.html)
>
> [35 U.S. Code § 173](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/USCODE-2011-title35/html/USCODE-2011-title35-partII-chap16-sec173.htm) - Term of design patent
>
> Patents for designs shall be granted for the term of fourteen years from the date of grant.
>
> [35 U.S. Code § 289](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/USCODE-2011-title35/html/USCODE-2011-title35-partIII-chap29-sec289.htm) - Additional remedy for infringement of design
> patent
>
> Whomever **during the term of a patent for a design**, without license of
> the owner, (1) applies the patented design, or any colorable imitation
> thereof, to any article of manufacture for the purpose of sale, or (2)
> sells or exposes for sale any article of manufacture to which such
> design or colorable imitation has been applied shall be liable to the
> owner to the extent of his total profit